# Les verbes ayant « se » devant ont-ils un nom, une désignation? Et pourquoi sont-ils ainsi?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, terminologie

Un ami anglophone me demandais pourquoi est-ce que certains verbes ont besoin de « *se* » devant le verbe? C'est alors que je me suis demandé s'il existait un terme pour les désigner?

J'en convient que selon les cas, il possible de remplacer ce « *se* » par « *s'être* »... mais comment peut-on expliquer que « s'être » est remplacé par « *se* » lors de la conjugaison ou vise-versa? Nous pouvons aussi faire l'observation avec la première personne mais avec cette fois « **me** » devient « **m'être** ». Et, contrairement à la première personne du pluriel, lui, se double : « **nous nous** » et divergence, nous ajoutons en plus le verbe d'état être « **Nous nous sommes** balancés ».

Comme par exemple :

- « Elle est partie **se** balancer [...] » selon le temps du verbe peut devenir;

  - « Elle dit **s'être** balancée [...] »
  - « Nous nous sommes balancés »
- « Elle ne **se** sent pas bien »

  - « Elle dit **s'être** mal sentie [...] »

Comment: L'ajout de *être* dans ces exemples sert à former l'infinitif « passé », ou plus exactement l'infinitif d'aspect accompli. C'est l'équivalent de *avoir* (*avoir marché*, *avoir réfléchi*) pour les verbes « normaux ». Et comme tu le remarques, c'est aussi l'auxiliaire utilisé pour le passé composé : « Nous nous sommes balancés ».

Comment: C'est quand même étrange comment nous l'utilisons sans se soucier réellement de ce qu'il en est réellement... Lorsqu'il vient le moment de l'expliquer alors là, ça se complique :P Merci @StéphaneGimenez

Comment: En plus de la réponse d'Archa, [ceci](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/les-verbes-pronominaux-32.php) peut aider !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ces verbes sont des verbes pronominaux (en anglais *reflexive verb*). Voici pourquoi on les utilise (source : [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Conjugaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais/Participe_pass%C3%A9#Conjugaison_pronominale)) :

> En grammaire française, un verbe pronominal est un verbe qui est toujours conjugué avec un pronom complément renvoyant au sujet. Cette construction peut correspondre à différents sens :
>
> Sens réfléchi : « *Elle se regarde dans le miroir* » : l'action est *regarder*, l'agent est *Elle*, identique à l'objet.
>
> Sens réciproque : « *Elles se combattent* » : l'action est de *combattre*, l'agent est à a fois *L'une et l'autre*, l'objet est *l'une l'autre* - l'agent et l'objet recouvrent les mêmes personnes.
>
> Sens passif : « *Ces voitures se vendent bien* » : l'action est *vendre*, l'objet (de la vente) est évidemment la voiture, l'agent de la vente n'est évidemment pas la voiture, sujet apparent. La forme pronominale à sens passif a précisément pour but de ne pas évoquer l'agent.
>
> Sens successif : « *Les jours se suivent* » : le sens est que un jour suit un autre jour, donc l'action est *suivre*, l'agent est *les jours*, et l'objet est *un autre jour* - dans ce cas l'objet est différent de l'agent.
>
> Les verbes « essentiellement pronominaux » ne peuvent prendre qu'une forme pronominale :
>
> « *Elles s'évanouissent* » : l'action est de *s'évanouir*, l'agent est *Elles*, par nature identique à l'objet.

La différence entre *se sentir* et *s'être senti* est qu'on ajoute *être*. C'est ce que je crois.