# Croiser les doigts : pronominal?

Tags: verbes-pronominaux

J’imaginais que l’expression en français pour *to cross one’s fingers* qui signifie faire le geste pour supplier de la chance ou d’éviter furtivement d’engager à une promesse était *se croiser les doigts* comme ***se** frotter les mains* ou ***se** couper les ongles* ou même ***se** croiser les **bras***. Mais en consultant Linguee [je trouve](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=i%27ve+got+my+fingers+crossed) que la forme pronominale est peut-être la moins commune. Et les exemples suggèrent que l’emploi du verbe au pronominal dans cette expression est plus commun au Canada qu’en France. Est-ce vrai?

Et surtout, y-a-t’il une régularité générale qui explique quelles actions s’expriment au pronominal?

Comment: En France je pense qu'on dit essentiellement  *croiser les doigts* (je n'ai pas toujours connu cette expression, je l'ai rencontré en anglais avant de la rencontrer en français (et je suis né en France, il y a très longtemps....). Que les Québécois calquent littéralement à l'anglais ne m'étonne pas. Je pense que tous les hexagonaux **se** coupent les ongles (sauf s'ils le font sur quelqu'un d'autre !) je croise les bras, je croise les jambes mais je ne suis pas sure de comprendre la dernière question, elle me semble un peu vague.

Comment: Quant à la dernière question, je suis anglophone, et pour ça les verbes pronominaux ne me viennent pas naturellement. Ce qui me conviendrait énormément c’est un système pour distinguer les actions corporelles qui s’expriment en verbes pronominaux des autres. On dit ***se** peigner les cheveux* mais non pas \* ***se** lever la main*, alors que oui, c'est ***se** casser le bras*.  Fault il apprendre chaque expression individue par cœur?

Comment: *Je lève la main*  : je fais une action mais pas sur ma personne, je ne subis pas l'action.  *je me casse le bras* : j'exerce une action sur ma personne, je subis l'action. On dit plutôt *se coiffer* (même si se peigner existe) : là aussi on fait une action sur soi, on subit l'action. *Je me brosse les dents* : je brosse des dents et ce sont mes dents que je brosse.  Je ne sais pas si la réponse à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14287/358) peut aider ?

Comment: À l’oreille anglophone, *I raised my hand* et *I injured my hand* semblent pour la plupart pareils. Ils experiment des actions que j’ai accomplies moi et dont le patient et le même, *my hand*. Mais chez les francophones, je crois comprendre que *J’ai levé la main* et *Je me suis blessé la main* ne s’approchent pas du tout, même en ce qui concerne le sentiment vague et général. C’est ça? Et alors, *se blesser la main* ne figurait pas parmi les choses that one can **do to** one’s hand?

Comment: Oui, je pense qu'on peut le dire comme ça. Quand je lève la main, il n'y a pas de contact physique avec ma main,  je ne fais qu'exercer mes muscles du bras pour la bouger, elle n'est pas touchée, ni par moi, ni par un agent extérieur que j'aurais activé par inadvertance (sol, couteau, etc...). Quand je me blesse la main, je suis à l'origine d'un mouvement qui fait que ma main subit un dommage.

Comment: Donc si j’avais un bras paralysé, je pourrais dire *Je me leve la main* pour indiquer que j’ai employé la main qui fonctionne encore pour saisir l’autre et la déplacer?

Comment: C'est tout à fait ça  !

Comment: Ah bon, d’accord. 

If you cared to digest all of this into an answer, I’d mark my question as answered. Otherwise I’ll piece it together and credit you.

Comment: Not sure we would really say "_je me lève la main_": you can, it's correct, but it's ambiguous because of that pronoun and there is a surprise factor, so we would go to "_j'utilise ma bonne main pour lever celle qui est blessée_" or similar.

Comment: @Frank *Je me vais te la lever, la main !* ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Et là, j'essaierais de ne pas te laisser faire ça, car cela a l'air un peu aggressif... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En France je pense qu'on dit essentiellement *croiser les doigts* pour conjurer le sort. En fait j'ai connu l'expression en anglais avant de la rencontrer en français et je soupçonne que ce soit un emprunt à l'anglais qui s'est répandu dans la deuxième moitié du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Le *Dictionnaire historique en langue française* donne les deux : *croiser les doigts* et *se croiser le doigts* sans préciser que *se croiser les doigts* serait essentiellement Québécois. *Croiser* les doigts est plus dans la logique d'emploi des verbes pronominaux en français que *se croiser les doigts* parce que, sauf cas très marginal (paralysie, etc.), je ne me croise pas les doigts d'une main à l'aide de mon autre main.

Les verbes pronominaux indiquent que le sujet fait l'action sur lui-même, il fait une action et en subit une en conséquence.
Quand *je lève la main* il n'y a pas de contact physique avec ma main, je ne fais qu'exercer ma volonté et mes muscles du bras pour la bouger, ma main  n'est pas touchée, ni par moi, ni par un agent extérieur. Quand *je me blesse la main*, j'indique à la fois que suis à l'origine du mouvement et que dans ce mouvement ma main est touchée et blessée, soit par une autre partie de mon corps, soit par un agent extérieur que j'aurais activé par inadvertance (sol, couteau, etc...), je subis quelque chose (ici un dommage). Quand je *me casse le bras*, je suis à l'origine d'un mouvement qui a pour conséquence que mon bras est cassé. Quand *je me brosse les dents*, je manipule la brosse à dents  et je « subis »  l'action du frottement sur mes dents etc.

English does not indicate the pronominal meaning explicitly but uses a possessive adjective at some point to indicate the action is done onto oneself: "I brush **my** teeth", "I hurt **my** hand" (*je me brosse **les** dents*, *je me fais mal à **la** main*) or uses a reflexive pronoun ("I hurt **myself**") when the object is not specified.

Il y a différentes sortes de verbes pronominaux et ceci est bien résumé sur [cette page](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/verbes-pronominaux) du dictionnaire *Le Robert*.
Ceci dit ce n'est pas toujours aussi évident pour un non francophone de savoir si un verbe est pronominal ou non, c'est le cas pour les verbes dit  « essentiellement pronominaux », et il vaut peut-être mieux les apprendre par cœur (il existe des listes, pas toujours exhaustives<sup>1</sup>) ou consulter un dictionnaire.

---

Pour revenir sur l'expression  *croiser les doigts* j'ai trouvé deux sources qui concordent<sup>2</sup> pour dire que l'expression serait empruntée à l'anglais. [D'où vient l’expression “croiser les doigts ” ?](https://www.caminteresse.fr/culture/dou-vient-lexpression-croiser-les-doigts-1181006/) sur le site de *Ça m’intéresse* :

> Les Anglais, au début du XXe siècle, sont les premiers à user de cette expression pour souhaiter bonne chance à quelqu’un.

Et dans l'article [Crossed fingers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_fingers) de Wikipedia :

> The act of crossing fingers for luck or to ward off ill luck is a well-understood gesture in the UK and parts of Scandinavia, but less so in mainland Europe. Its earliest recorded reference dates back to 1912 and is linked to the ladder superstition.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Par exemple sur la [BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22941/la-grammaire/le-verbe/verbes-pronominaux/liste-de-verbes-essentiellement-pronominaux).</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Ou bien l'une a copié l'autre...</sup>